# Ruby on Rails - How to relate a comment model to a blog with no database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I am using the gem [postmarkdown](https://github.com/ennova/postmarkdown) to create a blog in RoR.  The Post model in the gem is not backed by a database (it uses ActiveModel). How would I go about relating a Comment model to the Post model for a blog that does not utilize a database for the blog posts?

For example, with a typical blog backed by an ActiveRecord database, I could set up the relations (such as)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments
```

However, in this case, I don't know the best way to create a comment model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Post is an activemodel, you can't setup relations using methods in activerecord. You can check out the README at [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel). It doesn't have that functionality.

One way you could to is simply define your own methods inside Post model.

```
class Post
  def comments
    Comment.where(:post_id => id)
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def post
    Post.find_by_id(post_id)
  end
end
```

Edit:
Ah, I just find a similar question, [Ruby on Rails 3 (3.1) ActiveModel Associations (tableless nested models)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593428/ruby-on-rails-3-3-1-activemodel-associations-tableless-nested-models). You can check out that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (sorry for the late reply). In this case, how should I handle my routes.rb? Is the comments resource a nested resource within posts?