# why don't rails tableless models include associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

After looking at a few tableless solutions in Rails ([virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus), [active_attr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr), activemodel) it's clear that Rails associations are not supported. My question is why not? Is there some obvious reason for this that I'm missing? Seems like associations would be extremely useful but in all the examples I've seen they're left out.

Comment: What do you mean not supported?  ActiveModel supports associations by `has_many :children` and `belongs_to :parent`

Comment: See this question for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593428/ruby-on-rails-3-3-1-activemodel-associations-tableless-nested-models

Comment: that is a question from 2011, try using the ActiveRecord official documentation instead - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Comment: @sircapsalot are you maybe talking about active RECORD? i'm talking about active model.

Comment: you have it tagged as "activerecord" :)   ActiveModel is an entity within ActiveRecord.  ActiveRecord itself is an MVC, where ActiveModel is the model.  But to your problem, have you TRIED using the associations found within that documentation i linked?

Comment: sorry, tag fixed! i'm specifically trying to use associations in tableless models.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to answer your question of why it is not supported by here is one way you could support it with Rails 4+. This would not require you to have a database table and would also give you access to things like validations, associations, and some callbacks like after_initialize.

```
class Tableless < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end

    def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
        columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
    end 

    attr_accessor :id, :name, :value

    has_many :stuff_things
    has_many :things, :through => :stuff_things

end
```